# VideoLan song change event for radio stream

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

I'm new to using programming vlc, I'm using python specifically python-vlc to play a internet radio station.

I have it playing the station but can't get the current track that is playing.
When I get the audio track info it returns Track 1 all the time.

Anyways, I am looking for a way to get the song change event.  It seems that it could be possible. Because vlc title bar shows the current playing song and windows pops up a notification of the new playing song.

I would prefer to get the change event with the song so that I don't have to poll to check to see if the name change.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an MPEG stream, there is no such thing as "songs". It's just an audio stream. Some radio stations do change metadata in between, so you might be able to check whether the stream title changes or something. But that's purely heuristic.

I guess the notification you see is also triggered by the metadata change.

Comment: Thanks!! you helped me look in the right direction.
Needed to get the media, parse it, then get the metadata now_playing.
One more thing is to try an figure out if there is an event that triggers when the meta data is updates.

Comment: On Linux desktops that have DBus, an MPRIS event is broadcast across the bus. Maybe that helps? I don't know what you are up to, but maybe MPRIS is the way to go anyway, instead of plugging into VLC directly ;)?

Comment: metadata does change but vlc event handler doesn't fire when it changes, so its either a bug or there is something im missing. Solution was to use the event that run on time playing change when I check to see if the title changed.

Comment: @user1086377 I've the same problem, take a look of what I'm doing here https://github.com/wdog/mini-radio-player-pycui/ with python-vlc